# Can you use an xml datasource with Dundas Chart for SharePoint (v2.5)?

Tags: sharepoint, charts, dundas

Can you use an xml datasource with Dundas Chart for SharePoint (v2.5)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can (i've been using Dundas Chart for ASP.NET), but you can read in the xml and create an array or IList of your data that will work as source for the chart control.